# jersey - @PreMatching doesn't work

Tags: rest, jersey, matching

I want to execute some code before any request matching :

```
@PreMatching
public class PreMatchingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("I am here");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, whatever the request, the console never write the sysout message.
Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to explicitly register it or have it scanned for with the `@Provider` annotation. `@PreMatching` isn't a replacement for `@Provider`.

If you are package scanning for resource classes (`@Path` annotated classes), then the `@Provider` annotation will also be picked up if it is in a package or sub-packages listed in the package(s) to scan.